# Why is System.nanoTime() returning such a large number, when that much time has not been elapsed?

Tags: java

So I'm pretty new at Java, but I'm making a text adventure game for CompSci, and this is my code for levels.

```
public static int level(int exp, Long time, int levelnum) {
  //Time is the time elapsed since the program started
    time = System.nanoTime();
    //I divi  de by 10,000,000 twice because that sqared is 100 trillion, the conversion factor between nano and second
   exp = (int)(Math.round(time/10000000));
   exp = Math.round(exp/10000000);
    //The exp, or experience, is the percent, under 100, of the way to the next level. 1 is 10%, 2 is 20, etc.
    while (exp > 10){
        //This loop will check to make sure exp is under 10. If not, it will add one to the level number, and then subtract 10 from the exp and check again.
        levelnum++;
        exp = exp - 10;
    } 
    
   int bar;
   bar =1; 
   //Bar is here because originally, I planned on this all being one method, the next one and this, and so I placed it in meaning for it to act as the return value. It has stayed the return value.
   System.out.println(levelnum + "\n" + exp + "\n" + time);
   //That was for debugging purposes, so I could see the levels data as it processed.
   progBar(levelnum, exp);
    return bar;

    
}
public static void progBar(int levelnum, int exp){
    char barOpen, barClose;
    String bar = "";
    String emptyBar;
    //I realize now that I could have just "[" + bar + "]", but at the time i didnt think of that
    barOpen = '[';
    barClose = ']'; 
    if (exp > 1){
        //ok so if the experience is greater than 1, then we repeat the = that many times. That way, we don't repeat it when we have one
    bar = "=".repeat(exp);
    }else if (exp <= 1){
    bar = "=";
    }
    //This makes sure we have the adequate space between the experience and the bar close
    emptyBar = " ".repeat(10-exp);
    System.out.println("You are currently level " + levelnum + "\n" + barOpen + bar + emptyBar + barClose);
     
}
```

When I ran this yesterday, it succeeded in the level barring. However, today System.nanoTime() has begun to give extremely large numbers, even in different machines, none of which accurately represent the time which has elapsed. How could I fix this?

Comment: 100 trillion is not the conversion factor between nano and second. You should divide by 1 billion _once_.

Comment: Nanotime is meant for measuring _intervals_, and nothing else. You record its value before you start a task, then you measure its value afterwards, and the difference is how many nanoseconds it took. It is _not_ meant to reflect any specific time, [as per the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()). The _only_ guarantee you get is that if you subtract two values you got using nanoTime(), the difference is the number of nanoseconds that elapsed between obtaining those values. Nothing else.

Comment: @The Man its in nano seconds, it represents the current time.

Comment: @Raghuveer according to the javadoc: "This method can only be used to measure elapsed time *and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time*. ".  It does not represent the "current time".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

The *only* meaning you should assign to `System.nanoTime` is to call it twice and compare the two values as an approximate number of elapsed nanoseconds. *Do not interpret* the two values as being anything other than as [minuend and subtrahend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtraction#Notation_and_terminology) (the two parts of a subtraction operation) for elapsed nanos.

```
Duration.ofNanos( System.nanoTime() - start )
```

## Large or small `nanoTime` is irrelevant

Read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()):

> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary origin time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative).

The **number returned by this method has no meaning** other than to be compared to another such returned value to track elapsed time on a scale of nanoseconds.

So whether the number returned is large or small is irrelevant. **Comparing the returned numbers between computers or JVMs is meaningless.**

In my experience, the numbers may be a count of nanoseconds since the host machine was booted. But you should *never* count on that. Such a fact is but a mere implementation detail. That detail may differ between Java implementations, or between host OSes.

Also, keep in mind that your computer hardware is not likely able to track time precisely by single nanoseconds. So elapsed time will be approximate.

The number returned represents [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). That means a billionth of a second. So your math is invalid.

## `Duration`

Java offers you a class to track a span of time unattached to the timeline on a scale of nanoseconds: [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html). So no need for you to do any math.

```java
long start = System.nanoTime() ;
…
Duration duration = Duration.ofNanos( System.nanoTime() - start ) ;
String report = duration.toString() ;
```

You may interrogate for the amount of elapsed time by calling the various `to…` methods.

Tips:

- If doing benchmarking, consider using the *jmh* library.
- If doing regular business-style apps, use `java.time.Instant` class to capture moments.

Comment: @Thilo My example code was incorrect. Fixed now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
//Time is the time elapsed since the program started
time = System.nanoTime();
```

No, it is not.

The actual number returned by `nanoTime` has no specific meaning. It can only be used to measure the duration of time that has passed between two calls to `nanoTime`. And those calls have to be within the same program run, on the same machine. It is not comparable between different runs, even on the same machine.